# RD gateway: intermittent Remoteapp Disconnected over https site

Tags: gateway

A pop-up opens with "users cant connect to the remote computer because the Remote Desktop Gateway server is temporarily unavailable. "

The users can login but upon clicking, they get this error.
This is intermittent so not easy to track. Most users work fine.

Windwos 2012 RD gateway/broker system
Gateway, broker, term servers are all in same subnet, no latency between those.
Could this be related to client's computer in some way?

Any guidance would be appreciated. As in which server and event log would be useful. I can't seem to find it on either broker or terminal but there are are 10 terminal servers so I would not know which the end-user was really connected to.